# How to configure json format when using jaxb annotations with jersey

Tags: jaxb, jersey, jackson

I am using jersey to expose a service which uses jaxb annotated classes to configure the look of the json.

I am trying to include the type directive in each json element. I do this by providing a Provider as such:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser.Feature;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping;

@Provider
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public class CmsContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

        ObjectMapper mapper;

        public CmsContextResolver() {
            mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            // @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include =
            // JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, property = "@type")
            mapper.configure(Feature.INTERN_FIELD_NAMES, true);
            mapper.enableDefaultTypingAsProperty(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, "@type"); 
        }

        @Override
        public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0) {
            return mapper;
        }
    }
```

And this provider is definitely being picked up.

```
10 May 2011 3:53:18 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Provider classes found:
  class com.afrozaar.cms.service.CmsContextResolver
```

But it is making no difference. The format of the json is unaffected.

As far as I can tell the problem stems from the fact that jersey is not using jackson to serialize? or that jersey is ignoring my jackson configuration overrides...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why your code isn't working, but this is what I use:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider;

@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JsonProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {

    public JsonProvider() {
        super();
        setMapper( myConfiguredObjectMapper );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, was going to answer my own question, but you saved me the trouble. That's what I did :-), configured my own jackson-json provider.

Comment: I had the same issue as the OP with Jersey 2.4 and Jackson 2.2.3 -- I was not able to have the runtime recognize a custom object mapper... Every solution I found was using Spring MVC -- which I am not -- except this.

Comment: I have been banging my head on the wall until I found your solution. Thanks.